# Why is $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}] = \{a_{0}, a_{1}\zeta, \dots, a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2}, a_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, where $p \geq 2$ is a prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number $\geq 2$ and $\zeta := \zeta_{p}$ a complex number where $\zeta \neq 1$ and $\zeta^p=1$, i.e., is a $p$th root of unity. This is a question from a brazillian book, *Introdução à Algebra* (Introduction to Algebra), by Gonçalves. A. This question is posted before the chapter about groups and galois theory, so it is purely an *splitting field* exercise:

> Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{p}] = \{a_{0}, a_{1}\zeta, \dots, a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2}, a_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

This comes right after a pretty similar question, where the polynomial that we look around is $x^5 -1$. I could not do this example either, even algebrically, writing down the solutions (using complex form) and trying to understand why the $\zeta^4$ root is gone. The maximum that I got is that $\zeta^4 = \bar{\zeta}$, but I could not find a way to span it whit his *"smaller brothers"*. So, any help with this is going to be great!

FYI, I know about galois theory, but this is not intended to be looked with this "deeper" eyes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with the fact that by definition $ \zeta_p $ is a root of the polynomial $ f(x) = x^p - 1 $.  Note this polynomial factors into $ f(x) = (x - 1)g(x) $.  What can you say about the minimal polynomial of $ \zeta_p $ given these observations?

Comment: @JakeMirra Yes, the minimal polynomial has degree $p-1$. That's why we can span the field with $\{1,\zeta, ... , \zeta^{p-1} \}$? I don't know if this is enough to conclude that.

Comment: Try writing $\zeta^{p-1}$ as a linear combination of elements in $\{1,\zeta,\dots,\zeta^{p-2}\}$. Hint: the minimal polynomial.

Comment: You mean $a_{0}+a_{1}\zeta+\cdots+a_{p-2}\zeta^{p-2}$

Comment: Hint: The roots of $x^p-1$ are $1,\zeta,\dots,\zeta^{p-1}$ and their sum is zero.